# C program to calculate matrix multiplication

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a C program that will calculate M<sup>N</sup> where M is a square matrix and N is an integer. Every time after I enter a value for N, however, it crashes. Would anyone be able to identify what's wrong with it? I would presume it's something with regards to pointers but I do not understand what changes need to be made to them. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double *multiply(int M, double **A, double **B) {
    double **C = (double **)malloc(M * sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        C[i] = (double *)malloc(M * sizeof(double));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < M; k++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return *C;
}

void arrcpy(int M, double **A, double **B) {
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            A[i][j] = B[i][j];
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    int i, j, N, M;

    printf("M = ");
    scanf("%d", &M);

    double **R = (double **)malloc(M * sizeof(double));
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        R[i] = (double *)malloc(M * sizeof(double));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            printf("R[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            scanf("%lf", &R[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("N = ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    double **C;
    arrcpy(M, C, R);
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        *C = multiply(M, C, R);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            printf("%lf ", C[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `double **C; arrcpy(M,C,R);` - where will `C` be pointing to?

Comment: @churill It should point to the result of A*B

Comment: Yes, it should. But before that. When you call `arrcpy`. Where _does_ it point to?

Comment: If you cannot grasp it from your source, please use a debugger.

Comment: FYI, the method of implementing arrays with `double **` is inefficient, and teachers, books, or institutions that teach it are of dubious quality.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with _however, it crashes_?  Your computer explodes? Do you get a message from the system? Is it _I have crashed, please ask for help in StackOverflow_ (sorry for the sarcasm) where is it?  can you post it? thanks.  Please, read how to post in the help pages to provide good info so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the best approach is to implement the [fast exponentiation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), illustrated in the code below.

The code shown allows you to use a special type of matrix, that just requires one `malloc()` call per matrix (I will not bother you with the problems in your code that has already been answered for in other answers)  The matrix (I provided `m_rows` and `m_cols` fields to be able to hold rectangular matrices, while the implementation focuses on the problem to solve, which is matrix power raising) is stored in a single block of memory that includes space for the `struct matrix` itself, the pointers for the array of rows, and the rows themselves (there should be no alignment issues, as all blocks have been addressed using pointer arithmetic properly).  It initializes the pointers to the proper places by moving two pointers of appropiate types (one `double` pointer for moving to the next cell, to initialize cells, and other `double *` to move to the next row pointer, for initializing the pointers to the rows)  The set of *provider functions* (all the ones prefixed with `prov_`) allow you to initialize the matrix in too many different ways, by using the same routine.  If `NULL` is provided as provider, then no cell initialization is done (e.g. in matrix multiplication, in which initialization is done by the product routine).  Study it as it is very fast.

I have implemented the matrix create routines (a single free() call to the returned value is enough to free the whole matrix) and operations for adding, initializing in several flavours (from a file, from an array, from a `FILE *` stream, ...  some of them are not used in the program, but are presented to illustrate usage hints anyway) so you will probably use it as a reference implementation.  All the routines reachable from `main()` have been tested, and the sample code uses a sample matrix and tests that the characteristical polynomial, when applied to the matrix, results in the zero matrix.  For the test case, the approach of using fast exponentiation is of no use, because we need to use all the powers from 0 to 4, but the `mat_pow()` routine is used anyway to show how it works.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* structure to hold all the data for a matrix.  See discussion
 * in comments to understand this structure. */
struct matrix {
    int m_rows, m_cols;
    double **m_data;
    double  *unused_1; /* not used.  Only to warrant the 
                        * alignment to double * values. */
    double   unused_2; /* same as before. */
};

/* this are simple providers of matrix data, depending on how we
 * want to initialize the matrix. */

/* initializes each element to a constant provided by reference
 */
double prov_const(void *cb_par, int row, int col)
{
    double *val_ref = cb_par;
    return *val_ref;
}

double prov_list(void *cb_par, int row, int col)
{
    double **p = cb_par;
    return *(*p)++;
}

double prov_copy(void *cb_par, int row, int col)
{
    struct matrix *src = cb_par;

    assert(row < src->m_rows && col < src->m_cols);
    return src->m_data[row][col];
}

/* initializes kroneker matrix. Identity */
double prov_ident(void *unused, int row, int col)
{
    return row == col ? 1.0 : 0.0;
}

/* provides elements from file stream */
double prov_file(void *cb_par, int row, int col)
{
    FILE *in = cb_par;
    double ret_val;
    if (isatty(fileno(in))) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "mat[%d][%d]: ",
                row, col);
        fflush(stderr);
    }
    int res = fscanf(in, "%lg", &ret_val);
    assert(res == 1);
    return ret_val;
}

/* this creates the whole matrix with just one malloc */
struct matrix *mat_creat(
    int rows, int cols, /* dimensions */
    double prov(void *cd, int row, int col), /* initializer */
    void *cd) /* initializer callback data */
{
    size_t total_cells = rows * cols;

    /* See discussion about alignment in the comments to
     * understand the code below. */
    struct matrix *ret_val = malloc(
        sizeof *ret_val
        + rows * sizeof *ret_val->m_data
        + total_cells * sizeof **ret_val->m_data);

    assert(ret_val != NULL);

    /* place the array with bigger element cell first,
     * to warrant the smaller data alignment */
    double **aux1; /* pointer to array of row pointers */
    double *aux2; /* pointer to array of double cells */
    if (sizeof *ret_val->m_data > sizeof **ret_val->m_data) {
        /* put the pointers to rows first, pointer is bigger */
        aux1 = (double **) (ret_val + 1); /* row pointers array */
        aux2 = (double *) (aux1 + rows); /* double row arrays */
    } else {
        /* put the cells first, double is bigger than pointer */
        aux2 = (double *) (ret_val + 1);
        aux1 = (double **) (aux2 + total_cells);
    }

    ret_val->m_rows = rows;
    ret_val->m_cols = cols;
    ret_val->m_data = aux1;

    /* start the build */
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        *aux1++ = aux2; /* the pointer to the row */
        if (prov) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                /* this provides each element of the row */
                *aux2++ = prov(cd, row, col);
            }
        } else {
            /* no provider, no cell initialization */
            aux2 += cols;
        }
    }
    return ret_val;
}

struct matrix *mat_add(struct matrix *dst, struct matrix *b)
{
    assert(dst->m_rows == b->m_rows
        && dst->m_cols == b->m_cols);

    for (int row = 0; row < dst->m_rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < dst->m_cols; col++) {
            dst->m_data[row][col] += b->m_data[row][col];
        }
    }
    return dst;
}

struct matrix *mat_mscalar(struct matrix *dst, double b)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < dst->m_rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < dst->m_cols; col++) {
            dst->m_data[row][col] *= b;
        }
    }
    return dst;
}

struct matrix *mat_prod(struct matrix *a, struct matrix *b)
{
    assert(a->m_cols == b->m_rows);

    struct matrix *ret_val
        = mat_creat(a->m_rows, b->m_cols, NULL, NULL);

    for(int row = 0; row < a->m_rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < b->m_cols; col++) {
            double accum = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < a->m_cols; k++) {
                accum += a->m_data[row][k]
                       * b->m_data[k][col];
            }
            ret_val->m_data[row][col] = accum;
        }
    }
    return ret_val;
}

trix *mat_pow(struct matrix *a, unsigned N)
{
    /* ensure matrix is square */
    assert(a->m_rows == a->m_cols);

    struct matrix *ret_val
        = mat_creat(a->m_rows, a->m_cols,
                prov_ident, NULL);

    if (N == 0) return ret_val;  /* a**0 -> I */

    /* search for most significant bit */
    unsigned bit = 0;
    while ((1 << bit) < N) bit++;
    bit = 1 << bit;

    while (bit) {
        /* square it */
        struct matrix *aux = mat_prod(ret_val, ret_val);
        free(ret_val); /* must free after multiplying */
        ret_val = aux; /* assign the new matrix. */

        if (bit & N) { /* multiply by a */
            aux = mat_prod(ret_val, a);
            free(ret_val);
            ret_val = aux;
        }
        bit >>= 1;
    }
    return ret_val;
}

ssize_t mat_print(struct matrix *m, FILE *out, char *fmt)
{

#define ACT() do{         \
        if (n < 0) {      \
            return n;     \
        } else {          \
            ret_val += n; \
        }                 \
    } while (0)

    ssize_t ret_val = 0, n;
    char *sep1 = "{";
    for (int row = 0; row < m->m_rows; row++) {
        n = fprintf(out, "%s", sep1);
        ACT();
        sep1 = ",\n ";
        char *sep2 = "{";
        for (int col = 0; col < m->m_cols; col++) {
            n = fprintf(out, "%s", sep2);
            ACT();
            sep2 = ", ";
            n = fprintf(out, fmt, m->m_data[row][col]);
            ACT();
        }
        n = fprintf(out, "}");
        ACT();
    }
    n = fprintf(out, "}\n");
    ACT();
    return ret_val;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    static double values[] = {
        1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 5.0, 6.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 7.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    };
    static double coefs[] = {
        1.0, -4.0, 6.0, -4.0, 1.0,
    };
    static double zero = 0.0;
    double *p = values;

    struct matrix *M = mat_creat(4, 4, prov_list, &p);
    printf("M =\n");
    mat_print(M, stdout, "%g");

    struct matrix *P = mat_creat(4, 4, prov_const, &zero);

    printf("P[M] = ");
    for (int coef = 0; coef <= 4; coef++) {
        if (coef) {
            if (coefs[coef] > 0.0) {
                printf(" +");
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("%g * %s", coefs[coef], coef ? "A" : "I");
        if (coef > 1) {
            printf("^%d", coef);
        }
    }
    printf(" =\n");
    for (int coef = 0; coef <= 4; coef++) {
        printf("M\n");
        mat_print(M, stdout, "%g");
        printf("**%d\n", coef);
        struct matrix *TN = mat_pow(M, coef);
        mat_print(TN, stdout, "%g");
        TN = mat_mscalar(TN, coefs[coef]);
        printf("*%lg\n", coefs[coef]);
        mat_print(TN, stdout, "%g");
        P = mat_add(P, TN);
        printf("+\n");
        mat_print(P, stdout, "%g");
        free(TN);
    }
    free(P);
    free(M);
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. There is a small alignment issue: the `double` array might be misaligned on 32-bit architectures: for example a 2x2 matrix will be allocated with this layout: **offset 0**: `struct matrix`, size 12 bytes, **offset 12**: 2 `double` pointers, size 8 bytes, **offset 20**: misaligned array of 4 `double`. You should round `sizeof *ret_val + rows * sizeof *ret_val->m_data` up to a multiple of `sizeof(double)` and adjust the pointers in `ret_val->m_data` accordingly.

Comment: in 32bit architectures 64bit `double` types always require multiple accesses, so its alignment is not an issue.  having aligned to a pointer (with is required by the row pointers array) makes alignment of `double`s to succeed.

Comment: this may be true on some architectures, such as i386 which is very flexible, but it is nevertheless a problem that may cause undefined behavior on other targets. For example some SIMD loads and stores instructions require 128-bit alignment on 64-bit platforms. The proposed fix is easy to implement and would cause minimal overhead on platforms where `sizeof(double) > sizeof(double *)` but may increase performance with better alignment as would be the case on 64-bit x86 running i386 code.

Comment: have you tested it?

Comment: Also note that there is a potential bug in the malloc size computation: you use `rows * cols * sizeof **ret_val->m_data` which will overflow if `rows * cols` exceeds the range of `int`. You should write `sizeof **ret_val->m_data * rows * cols`.

Comment: *Have you tested it?* Yes I have: I get a consistent penalty of 20% for 100x100 matrices with `-m32` code generation on my Macbook running OS/X 10.12.6 (to test 32-bit executables). The code is here: https://ghostbin.co/paste/bea3pb2

Comment: but your macbook is a 64 machine..... you got a 20% slower when running 32bit code in 64 bit arch.... That can be due to many things, unrelated to alignment.... Just try it on an 32bit true ARM or better, run it on a VAX or a SPARC (the sparc is specially ticky with nonaligned accesses) Anyway, IMHO, your alignment can be granted by the approach followed in my edit (just adding a `double *` and a `double` fields), without the need to calculate offsets, and using plain pointer arithmethic.  This way you don't have to guess how the compiler aligns data, and the code is far more portable.

Comment: The 20% hit is the difference between the aligned allocation and the unaligned allocation. It appears for large sizes where the multiplication algorithm tends to produce more cache misses. Your modification is a good solution to avoid pointer arithmetic. You could use a transparent union to avoid the overhead of the extra unused members. Btw computing `size_t total_cells = rows * cols;` does not fix the potential overflow in `row * cols`.

Comment: Nope.... you have switched your program to make **all accesses** 32bit, and you have eliminated the 64bit accesses at all.... check the file type.  It is like comparing the run of an ultimate ryzen cpu against a vax11/780  (even using a single core)  You are running even a different machine code totally.  The instruction sets are different... everything is different running a program in 32bit and 64bit mode in an intel/AMD computer.

Comment: Please, do a good test, and try this new example now.... find a single data misaligned with the version posted right now.  I have read a couple of hours ago that your test consisted in swthich to 32bit mode your 64bit computer..... that's shame.  And believe me.... 64 bit doubles are read in two memory accesses in 32bit platforms, so they are never misaligneed.  this is because the architecture is 32bit, simply.  I could admit before that data is misaligned if rows and columns are both odd numbers.... but now even when both rows and cols are odd, all doubles are aligned to a double address.

Comment: I get the same performance from the 32-bit and the 64-bit code, no shame at all, as a matter of fact, I get the same 20% penalty in 64-bit if I artificially misalign the `double` array by 4 bytes. Reads are performed through the caches, misaligning the data increases the number of cache misses in both 32- and 64-bit CPUs. Proper alignment is a must for portability and performance, and your solution now achieves that. Misalignment actually happened before if the number of rows was even, regardless of the number of columns.

Comment: So, are you telling me that my code has an issue on alignment because it losses  20% throughput when run on a machine that is emulating 32bit code but _can transparently_ act in 64bit mode as it is its native mode, making 64 bit accesses and this makes it to slow down when doing unaligned 32bit accesses?  Look, this example was to show how all malloc() calls can be merged into one single call... I admitted the alignment problem in the first approach, but I have refused to use your approach because it does it by caclulating offsets and doing double casts (unnecesary) to illustrate your...

Comment: fact you have make a little trick... is forcing the compiler to compileyour sample code for a 32 bit machine and run it in a 64bit machine, capable of making 64bit accesses.  Just to state that you are right.  Let me explain you something.  This sample is just to illustrate how to do things to a newbie, as professional libraries take advantage of the use of multiple cores to run vectorial algebra operations and this means that normally matrices are divided in boxes of eight rows and columns in order to make each multiplication to fit completely in a processor cache line, so you ...

Comment: get real advantage on the processor accesses.  In my humble opinion, you are discussing a topic that is completely out of scope here.... most probably with the wrong person, so you are lossing your time, and what is worse, mine.... I'm not going to answer more questions about your 20% loss in that strambotic case.  I recommend you not to focus on this simple problem and attack the more complex, multithreaded and cache optimized case of matrix multiplication.  Thanks for your two cents, anyway.

Comment: We are on the same page here, trying to help newbies and others too. Your post is a good illustration of C's versatility and is quite useful for all programmers. It is sad I am the single upvoter in 3 years.  I merely pointed to you 2 small but tricky issues and provided at your request a contrived example of potential consequences. Other architectures could have no noticeable impact or could fail with a misaligned access, not every computer is a Vax as we both remember :). Sorry for wasting our time arguing on these silly issues, have a great Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @tshiono already points out a number of problems in OPs code like `C` being used uninitialized, wrong dynamic allocation, etc.

This answer will suggest an alternative method for memory allocation.

The approach used by OP is an array of M pointers where each pointer points to an array of M double. This approach requires that the array of M pointers is first allocated by one `malloc` call and then a loop with a `malloc` for each array of double. That is M+1 `malloc` calls for a single matrix.

This can be simplified to a single `malloc` by declaring the matrix variable as **a pointer to an array of M double**. Like

```
double (*R)[M] = malloc(M * sizeof *R);
\------------/   \-------------------/
 R is a pointer   Allocate M x M doubles
 to an array      in a single malloc call
 of M double
```

Likewise, freeing an object of this type will only require one call of `free` instead of M+1 calls.

Another benefit is that the matrix will be stored in one contiguous memory block. This allows for using `memcpy` for copying a matrix instead of writing a custom function.

This could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void multiply(int M, double (*restrict result)[M], double (*A)[M], double (*B)[M])
{
  for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<M; j++) {
      result[i][j] = 0;
      for(int k=0; k<M; k++) {
        result[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
      }
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, N, M;

    printf("M = ");
    if (scanf("%d",&M) != 1) exit(1);

    double (*R)[M] = malloc(M * sizeof *R);
    double (*C)[M] = malloc(M * sizeof *C);
    double (*T)[M] = malloc(M * sizeof *T);
    if (R == NULL || C == NULL || T == NULL) exit(1);

    for(i=0; i<M; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<M; j++) {
            printf("R[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            if (scanf("%lf", &R[i][j]) != 1) exit(1);
        }
    }

    printf("N = ");
    if (scanf("%d",&N) != 1) exit(1);

    memcpy(C, R, M * sizeof *R);

    for(i = 1; i < N; i++) {
      multiply(M, T, C, R);
      memcpy(C, T, M * sizeof *R);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            printf("%lf ", C[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(R);
    free(C);
    free(T);

    return 0;
}
```

In the code above it's a bit annoying that the result of the multiplication ends in `T` and then it's copied to `C` for the next loop iteration. We can avoid that by changing:

```
    memcpy(C, R, M * sizeof *R);

    for(i = 1; i < N; i++) {
      multiply(M, T, C, R);
      memcpy(C, T, M * sizeof *R);
    }
```

to

```
    // Make sure that an even number of multiplications is needed after this block
    if (N > 1 && (N & 1) == 0) {
      multiply(M, C, R, R);
      --N;
    } else {
      memcpy(C, R, M * sizeof *R);
    }

    // Do two multiplications in each loop
    for(i = 1; i < N; i += 2) {
      multiply(M, T, C, R);
      multiply(M, C, T, R);
    }
```

A bit more complex but it avoids a `memcpy` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * multiply square (MxM) matrices: A = B * C
 */
void multiply(int M, double **A, double **B, double **C)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            A[i][j] = 0;        // initialize cells
            for(int k = 0; k < M; k++) {
                A[i][j] += B[i][k] * C[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
 * copy square (MxM) matrix: A := B
 */
void matcpy(int M, double **A, double **B)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            A[i][j] = B[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, N, M;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];

    printf("M = ");
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
    sscanf(buf, "%d", &M);

    double **R = malloc(M * sizeof(double *));
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        R[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(double));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            printf("R[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
            sscanf(buf, "%lf", &R[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("N = ");
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
    sscanf(buf, "%d", &N);

    double **S = malloc(M * sizeof(double *));
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        S[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(double));
    }
    double **C = malloc(M * sizeof(double *));
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        C[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(double));
    }

    matcpy(M, S, R);
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        multiply(M, C, R, S);
        matcpy(M, S, C);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            printf ("%lf ", S[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

- The main reason of the crash is the code `arrcpy(M,C,R)` where the matrix C is
  not allocated yet.
- The code `double **R = malloc(M * sizeof(double))` should be `double **R = malloc(M * sizeof(double *))`,
  although the former just happens to work.
- It is not a good idea to allocate the matrix C each time within the multiply
  function especially when you perform the successive multiplications.
- It is recommended to use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` instead of `scanf()`
  to be robust against irregular inputs.

Comment: Nitpick: While I in general agree about `fgets` and `sscanf`, it doesn't matter much when no code checks the return values. Further, it's worth to mention that use of `scanf` allows multiple values on the same line. Your code requires each value to be on seperate lines.

Comment: @4386427 thanks for the suggestion. That's right. I'll update soon.

Comment: @4386427: More than that, because the arrays are implemented as pointers-to-pointers and there parameters are not marked with `restrict`, the compiler cannot know whether any `A[i][j]` overlaps any `B[i][k]` or `C[k][j]`, so it has to store and reload `A[i][j]` in each iteration of the inner loop. `double **` should not be used to implement arrays, `restrict` should be used to tell the compiler the arrays are separate, and the loop should accumulate the sum in a local variable and just store it in the array once.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{int n,P,k;
    printf (" type the number of lines and colons :  ");
scanf ("%d",&n);
    int MUL1[n][n], MUL2[n][n], MUL[n][n];
     int i,j;
     printf ("type the elements of the first matirx : \n");
     for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
            {printf (" [%d,%d]: ",i,j);
             scanf ("%d",&MUL1[i][j]);}}

     printf ("type the elements of the second matirx :  \n");
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
            {printf (" [%d,%d]: ",i,j);
             scanf ("%d",&MUL2[i][j]);}}

    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
            {
                MUL[i][j]=0; 
                for ( k=1;k<=n ; k++)
                {
                       MUL[i][j] = MUL[i][j] + MUL1[i][k] * MUL2[k][j];
                }
            }
    }
    printf ("MAT1 * MAT2 = ");
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {printf ("\n");
        for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
            {printf (" %d ",MUL[i][j]);}}
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow! This platform is not only about providing code, but more about explaining things. It's great that you want to help people, but currently your answer is not really helpful. One reason is, that you don't explain what's actually wrong in the original code. You also don't explain what you've changed and why. And lastly, I'm sorry to say, but your code is filled with bugs. You can find more informations here: [help]