# 2D matrix multiplication in c

Tags: arrays, c, 2d

I have written a code in C language for matrix multiplication. There is no error, but the desired output is not coming, which part of my code is wrong or had I miss something.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int r1, c1, r2, c2;
    int a[r1][c1];
    int b[r2][c2];
    int c[r1][c2];
    int i, j;
    printf("enter row1 and col1:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &r1, &c1);
    printf("enter row2 and col2:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &r2, &c2);
    if (c1 == r2) {
        printf("enter element of 1st matrix:");
        for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
                scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n-----------------");
        printf("enter element of 2nd matrix:");
        for (i = 0; i < r2; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
                scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
            }
        }
    
        printf("the resultant matrix is:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
                c[i][j] += a[i][j] * b[j][i];
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
                printf("%d\t", c[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here: `int r1,c1,r2,c2; int a[r1][c1];` What are the values of `r1`and `c1` at this point? What is the size of the array?

Comment: If you're using gcc or clang, compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. If you're using microsoft's compiler, compile with `/W4 /WX`.

Comment: you cannot (in a portable way) dimension a matrix with rows and columns coming from a dynamic expression  (like a variable name) but from a constant value (e.g. 28).  More on if the variables you use have not been initialized (which means they can have any value)  don't say in public _There is no error_, as you are betting for having one (in this case at least three)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- the arrays `int a[r1][c1];`, `int b[r2][c2];`, `int c[r1][c2];` are defined before `r1` and `c1` have been read from the user: the code has potential undefined behavior as `r1` and `c1` are uninitialized, thus have indeterminate values: the allocation of the arrays may fail or cause undefined behavior if the sizes happen to be negative and accessing them with index values iterating up to different boundary values entered by the user will have undefined behavior.
- you verify that the number of columns of `a` is equal to the number of rows of `b`, but you should also check that all dimensions are positive to avoid potential undefined behavior.
- Defining the matrices as variable length arrays with automatic storage is risky: large sizes may cause a **stack overflow**.  Allocating the matrices from the heap is recommended.
- the multiplication algorithm is incorrect: you must implement a triple loop and initialize the target element at `c1[i][j]` before the inner loop.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int r1, c1, r2, c2;
    printf("enter row1 and col1:\n");
    if (scanf("%d%d", &r1, &c1) != 2)
        return 1;
    printf("enter row2 and col2:\n");
    if (scanf("%d%d", &r2, &c2) != 2)
        return 1;
    if (r1 <= 0 || c1 <= 0 || r2 <= 0 || c2 <= 0 || c1 != r2) {
        printf("invalid matrix sizes\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
#if !defined ALLOCATE_MATRICES_FROM_THE_HEAP
        // if the dimensions are small, you can define the matrices as
        int a[r1][c1], b[r2][c2], c[r1][c2];
#else
        // for large sizes, you can allocate the matrices from the heap this way:
        int (*a)[c1] = calloc(sizeof(*a), r1);
        int (*b)[c2] = calloc(sizeof(*b), r2);
        int (*c)[c2] = calloc(sizeof(*c), r1);
        if (a == NULL || b == NULL || c == NULL) {
            printf("out of memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
#endif
        printf("enter elements of 1st matrix:");
        for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
                a[i][j] = 0;
                scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n-----------------");
        printf("enter elements of 2nd matrix:");
        for (int i = 0; i < r2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
                b[i][j] = 0;
                scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
            }
        }
    
        printf("the resultant matrix is:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
                int v = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < c1; k++) {
                    v += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
                c[i][j] = v;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
                printf("%5d\t", c[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n\n");
        }
#if defined ALLOCATE_MATRICES_FROM_THE_HEAP
        free(a);
        free(b);
        free(c);
#endif
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am just starting to learn code that's this small problems are coming on my way.

Comment: @KiranRai: glad to help. You can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is not _potential_ it's indeed a fact! :)

Comment: Why are you allocating the matrices in such a complicated way?  You declare an array of variable number of arguments (which is something you try to avoid in the explanation you give) to dynamically allocate a dynamic number of integers, that you later have to free.

Comment: @LuisColorado: the values of the dimensions are indeterminate, defining the arrays with a negative or zero size or a size larger then local constraints allow has undefined behavior, so UB is very likely at that stage, and if it is not the case, another type of UB will occur if the actual sizes entered by the user are incompatible with the actual definition, further increasing the likelihood of UB occurring, making it extremely likely. This amendment follows a previous discussion with Ricci.

Comment: @LuisColorado: `int (*a)[c1] = calloc(sizeof(*a), r1);` allocates a 2D array from the heap. It allocates `r1` consecutive objects each of type `int[c1]`, the pointer `a` can be used to refer to matrix elements as `a[i][j]`, which is the goal.  If dimensions are known to be rather small, allocating 2D arrays with automatic storage as `int a[r1][c1];` is a palatable alternative. Both definitions require VLA support. Without VLA support, allocating an array of pointers to arrays is possible, but more complicated and less efficient. Your solution is a good portable alternative for small matrices.

Comment: This is not the point.  The point is that the answer talks about not using variable dimension arrays, and you solve only half of it.... by dynamically allocating the other half, with `calloc()` but you still allocate the array of pointers dynamically, using the variable array dimension feature.  You cannot say that it is not completely portable using vda and then provide a half solution that reduces vda to just one dimension arrays (as it is still using vda)  Anyway, this is of low or no importance here.

Comment: @LuisColorado: *the answer talks about not using variable dimension arrays*... no, I only say it is risky to define these with automatic storage for large sizes and recommend allocating from the heap.

Comment: ok, but then you describe a solution that uses variable dimensioned arrays again, complicating things by the use of `calloc()` (which is not necessary with full vda's)

Comment: @LuisColorado: it is a complicated syntax, rarely used and probably puzzling to many a C programmer. Yet it allows for any positive matrix dimensions, within available heap space. C is definitely not the best choice for matrix computations with runtime defined sizes.

Comment: The use of calloc introduces the need to free() the allocations after use, which is another unnecesarry risk.  I agree that using it for automatic variables leads to overflowing the stack space easily.  I would resign to use objects for this.  I have an elegant solution in one of my last answers.  [Check it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67564797/c-program-to-calculate-matrix-multiplication/67593724#67593724).  Just look for the `mat_create()` implementation.

Comment: @LuisColorado: your solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67593724/4593267 is interesting: combining an indirect 2D matrix for access and a flat 2D matrix for storage.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
int r1, c1, r2, c2;
int a[r1][c1];   // at this point r1 c1, r2, c2 etc.
int b[r2][c2];   // are not yet initialized and their
int c[r1][c2];   // content is undetermined. Therefore
                 // the size of the arrays a, b and C are
                 // undetermined leading to the problem you encounter
```

You want this:

```
int r1,c1,r2,c2;
int i,j;
printf("enter row1 and col1:\n");
scanf("%d%d",&r1,&c1);
printf("enter row2 and col2:\n");
scanf("%d%d",&r2,&c2);

int a[r1][c1];  // here r1, c1, r2, c2 etc.
int b[r2][c2];  // have determined values
int c[r1][c2];
```

There might be more problems further in your code, I didn't check.

Comment: @KiranRai you should accept one of the answers.  chqrlie's answer is the best and most complete IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The program you post dimensions the three matrices with undefined values coming from uninitialized variables.  You can, at least, dimension those variables once you know the values of the dimensions, as in (please, read my comments in your code, as they state problems in your code you have not realized):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int r1, c1, r2, c2;
    int i, j;
    printf("enter row1 and col1:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &r1, &c1);
    printf("enter row2 and col2:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &r2, &c2);
    int a[r1][c1];  /* declare the dimensions <<<after>>> you know what values are */
    int b[r2][c2];  /* to be given. */
    int c[r1][c2];

    if (c1 == r2) { /* put an else statement to this if indicating the cause of */
            /* not making any calculation in case r2 and c1 not being equal */
        printf("enter element of 1st matrix:");
        for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
                scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n-----------------");
        printf("enter element of 2nd matrix:");
        for (i = 0; i < r2; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
                scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
            }
        }
    
        printf("the resultant matrix is:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c2; j++) { /* you need three nested loops, not two */
                /* ALL YOUR CODE HERE IS BAD, USE THIS INSTEAD */
                int k;
                c[i][j] = 0; /* initialize c[i][j] to zero or you'll get weird values */
                for (k = 0; k < c1; k++) { /* YOU NEED ANOTHER LOOP */
                    c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
                printf("%d\t", c[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but it is more portable to give your matrices maximum dimensions and work only in the subbox delimited by the values of `r1`, `c1`, `r2`, `c2`, `r3` and `c3`.  As in:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_DIM 10

int main()
{
    int r1, c1, r2, c2;
    int i, j; /* why didn't you call these r and c (for row and column resp.)? */

    /* this will loop on input until you give correct values for all dimensions, */
    do {
        printf("enter row1 and col1:\n");
        scanf("%d%d", &r1, &c1);
        printf("enter row2 and col2:\n");
        scanf("%d%d", &r2, &c2);
    } while (r1 <= 0 || r1 > MAX_DIM || c1 <= 0 || c1 > MAX_DIM ||
             r2 <= 0 || r2 > MAX_DIM || c2 <= 0 || c2 > MAX_DIM ||
             c1 != r2);

    int a[MAX_DIM][MAX_DIM]; /* more portable this way, as variable dimensioning */
    int b[MAX_DIM][MAX_DIM]; /* is not present in all standard editions */
    /* there's no need to have matrix c as we are not doing anything with it. 
     * (see below why)*/

    printf("enter element of 1st matrix:");
    for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n-----------------");

    printf("enter element of 2nd matrix:");
    for (i = 0; i < r2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    printf("the resultant matrix is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
            int k;
            int cell_value = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < c1 /* or k < r2, both are the same */; k++) {
                    cell_value += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
            /* cell_value is the value of product matrix at [i][j] */
            printf("%d\t", cell_value);
        }
        printf("\n\n"); /* new line for each row */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you see, this last sample doesn't require to have stored the product matrix `c`, as you can print the elements (which are generated per rows, then per columns) as they are calculated.

Comment: Your solution is elegant if a maximum size for each dimension is acceptable.

Comment: You can also improve portability to pre-C99 compilers by moving the matrix definitions before the `do` / `while` loop.

Comment: nope.... allocating an array of 0 elements will give you no storage area to work.  So the dimensions must be 1 at least.

Comment: Oh... that's right... sorry... my mistake.... :)  Edited.  Now it should be correct.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int r1,c1,r2,c2;
   
    int i,j;
    printf("enter row1 and col1:\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&r1,&c1);
    printf("enter row2 and col2:\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&r2,&c2);
     int a[r1][c1];
    int b[r2][c2];
    int c[r1][c2];
    if(c1==r2){
        printf("enter element of 1st matrix:");
        for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
            for(j=0;j<c1;j++){
                scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n-----------------");
        printf("enter element of 2st matrix:");
        for(i=0;i<r2;i++){
            for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
                scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
            }
    }
    
    printf("the resultant matrix is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
            c[i][j]=0;
            for(int k=0;k<c1;k++)    
              {    
           c[i][j]+=a[i][k]*b[k][j];    
              } 
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
            printf("%d\t",c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    
    
}
return 0;
    
    
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.

Comment: Ya it's my first post and i was not able to put tags in it.